# ¿Cómo sustituir la función Delay? (evitar bloqueos) en arduino

Tags: c, arduino

¿Alguien sabe como sustituir la función Delay, que provoca retrasos, en arduino? Es que intento medir distancias con este código, pero a la vez no quiero que todo el sistema se "duerma" ese tiempo, quiero hacer varias cosas a la vez medir distancias y que pueda seguir mandando ordenes a mi sistema.

```
int Trig=4;
int Echo=3;

//Variable en la que se va a almacenar el valor correspondiente a la distancia
int Dist;

void setup() {
    pinMode (Trig, OUTPUT);
    pinMode (Echo, INPUT);
}

//Este módulo calcula y devuelve la distancia en cm.
void ultrasonido (int &Distancia){
    //Para estabilizar el valor del pin Trig se establece a LOW
    digitalWrite (Trig, LOW);
    delay(10);
    //Se lanzan los 8 pulsos
    digitalWrite (Trig, HIGH);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite (Trig, LOW);
    Distancia= pulseIn (Echo, HIGH);
    Distancia=Distancia/58;
    Serial.println(Distancia);
    delay(100);
}

void loop() {
    ultrasonido(Dist);
    delay (250);
}
```

Comment: la distancia se mide en metros, pulgadas, pies, etc... pues son distancias :) ¿es correcto asumir que quieres medir el tiempo?.. lo que es mas confuso de la pregunta es que _delay_ *no* se usa para medir ni distancia ni tiempo, sino para esperar un tiempo dado...es decir para _dormir_ el hilo (o thread). Si quieres medir cuanto tiempo ocupa una operación, te recomiendo que cheques la documentacion de [millis](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis), tomando una muestra antes y otra despues y calculando la diferencia es sencillo saber cuanto tiempo ha transcurrido.

Comment: Perdón pero no entiendo porque esta puesto en espera, @tomas esta calculado la distancia en CM de una imagen (asumo que de un ultrasonido) y no quiere que el código se bloquee al usar delay.

Comment: @tomas, yo tuve un problema similar, enviaba una señal que indicaba el número de botón a un telefono android por el jack de audio, pero se bloqueaba durante la trasmisión y al presionar muy rápido no se detectaba porque no se encolaba las señales, me recomendaron usar millis, pero termine usando el modulo de bluethoot para poder encolar los llamados al botón. Esta fue mi pregunta en el foro de arduino de stackenchage (en inglés) http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/14713/digitalwrite-queued-signals

Comment: soy nuevo en esto y estoy intentando aprender (frase muy comun en estos dias). Quiriera que por favor me explicaran la siguiente sentencia digitalWrite( led, on ? HIGH : LOW ); se que es para acmbiar el estado de la salida digital, pero ¿como funciona? , cual es su sintaxis?

Answer (score 5):

Quizás algo de lo siguiente lo ayude dependiendo de lo que desee conseguir a largo plazo o el que mas se ajuste a sus necesidades:

No hay *multi-threading* ni *multi-proceso*, En Arduino por lo menos hasta donde yo se, no se apoya (hardware) threading.

Usted puede tratar de simular múltiples hilos con algún software/librería.

Por ejemplo:

**Protothreads**, aunque existen varias:

Protothreads puede ayudarle en esa tarea pues son hilos 
Stackless extremadamente ligeros diseñados para sistemas 
de memoria restringido como pueden ser sistemas embebidos pequeños.

> (link) Protothreads http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/

O usar las *interrupciones*, en especial cronometradas. Se puede programar un temporizador
para interrumpir la rutina principal cada tanto tiempo (micro segundos),
para así simular lo que busca ejecutando una u otra rutina especifica.
para para así hacer cosas mientras se hacen otras cosas

> (link) https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Interrupts

---

He buscado algún código similar a lo comentado para mostrarle y este es el que encontré puede verlo debajo con su link en la respuesta de un usuario de `electronics.stackexchange.com` quizás lo ayude.

> https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67089/how-can-i-control-things-without-using-delay/67091#67091
>
> En el ejemplo de abajo,  el LED parpadea sin usar delay(). Cuando se ejecuta
>   Timer1,   se llama la rutina de servicio de interrupción (ISR)
>   isrBlinker ()  cambiando el estado del LED entre encendido / apagado.
>
> Para demostrar que otras cosas pueden suceder simultáneamente,  loop ()
>   escribe repetidamente foo / bar al puerto serie  independiente del LED
>   parpadeante.

```
#include "TimerOne.h" 

int led = 13;

void isrBlinker() {
  static bool on = false;
  digitalWrite( led, on ? HIGH : LOW );
  on = !on;
}

void setup() {                
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.flush();
  Serial.println("Serial initialized");

  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);

  // initialize the ISR blinker
  Timer1.initialize(1000000);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt( isrBlinker );
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("foo");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("bar");
  delay(1000);
}
```

---

> videos que quizás podrían ayudarte

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeP_NiajWME

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esta libraría pera sensores de ultrasonidos de arduino

[NewPing](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/NewPing#Features)

Seguramente te permitirá mejorar el tiempo de respuesta.

Ejemplo de la pagina:

```
#include <NewPing.h>

#define TRIGGER_PIN  12
#define ECHO_PIN     11
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  delay(50);
  int uS = sonar.ping();
  Serial.print("Ping: ");
  Serial.print(uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM);
  Serial.println("cm");
}
```

En caso de que quieras eliminar la necesidad de esperar al sensor, por ejemplo que el loop corra hasta que el sensor disponga de mediciones, te recomendaría utilizar un sensor en bus i2c tipo SRF10 o SRF08 que te permitirán recoger la medición en cuanto este disponible sin necesidad de "delay".

Revisa el siguiente enlace:

[Sensor ultrasonidos i2c](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SFRRangerReader)

Answer (score 1):

La función millis() es lo que necesitas. Ya que esta trabaja sobre el tiempo desde que se inició el arduino, con ella puedes "falsear" los delay() sin tener que "bloquear" el procesador. Hay un tutorial muy bueno sobre su uso en adafruit   https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/overview
Suerte :)